# Font weights shifting up when underlying CSS Transition finishes

Tags: html, css

Here's the site:

www.wearethefirehouse.com/phasetest

If you slowly scroll, you'll notice that once the menu bar is fully opaque, the `nav li` items all jump up from Enzo 300 (as seen on page load with no nav background), to Enzo 600... tough to tell at that size if it's an entire weight class but they're definitely fattening.

Still not sure which I'm going to end up using on an aesthetic level, but how can I stop it from switching to the fatter weight? In all the CSS related to the nav, (unless I'm missing something), I only have `font-weight: 600` in use, not 300. So it should be either all 300 or all 600, pre- and post-transition.

```
.navbar-default {
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #222;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    font-family: "ff-enzo-web", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FC6C00;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:active,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand.active {
    color: #fec503;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.02);        
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #FC6C00;
    background-color: #FC6C00;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #FC6C00;
}

.navbar-default .nav li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "ff-enzo-web",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: color .5s ease;
}

.navbar-default .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav li a:focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #FC6C00;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a {
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #363636;
    background-color: #FC6C00;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FC6C00;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Note: any other nav-related CSS I have is just adjustments of the above for the sake of responsive breakpoints, but the problem exists at full-width so I don't think that's it.

Comment: The problem you're describing sounds to me like a known issue in chrome. A solution used by some is to set `-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased`. Note that this is a hack fix and *should never be used on large amounts of text* (see here for a rant on the subject: http://usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/)

Comment: That would be fine except it's in Safari too.... gonna try @Vishu's suggestion below.

Comment: Safari is also WebKit (chrome is actually a branch of WebKit called blink now, but they're still very similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing any weight changes in the font on scroll, however I did notice the abrupt jump due to the padding change when navbar shrinks, seems you have a transition in place but that doesn't work for the padding property as the duration is not specified with it.

Following adjustment to the `.navbar-default` block makes the transition work for both padding and bg color, please note the added time delay after padding -

```
transition: padding 0.5s, background-color .7s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: THANK YOU. Ugh, that was driving me nuts. I'm still learning CSS, still bummed I didn't catch that. Also, my fonts thickening appears to only be in Safari. Tested in FF and its all peachy. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is not in this code

and I also think problem is not with font weight

problem is where you change your header its padding disappear try to check that out...

sorry if that not helps